# Angular how to show a loading cursor on Angular File Upload

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a file upload that works as expected however on our server it takes a while before the file dialog box pops up.

How can I intercept the call and show a loading screen or even a wait cursor until the file dialog finally opens

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Choose File</label>
    <input type="file"
           id="file"
          #input
           (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
  <button type="button" (click)="showLoader(); input.click();">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

The handleFileInput works fine when the user selects a file to upload, however there is a 5 - 7 second wait time between the user clicking the "Choose File" button and the dialog box showing up

EDIT this is the dialog box that I am referring to
[image]

EDIT#2:
So based on an answer below I figured that I could call two events with the click function of the button.  I am able to get the loading screen to show while the dialog box is getting itself together, but the issue now is if the user hits the cancel button of the dialog box. The loading screen doesnt go away.

Comment: that is a huge amount of time for the user to wait just for the dialog appears. or maybe I got it wrong. or do you mean that the time is for the file to be uploaded.

Comment: Yes that is correct. That windows file picker dialog takes a while to load on our machines. I need to show a loading screen inbetween that time or change the cursor to something. Currently the user just clicks the button multiple times as there is no indication anything is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular material, then you can use the mat-spinner component. Check the link. https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview

Basically you just implement the mat-spinner inside your html, and then you can use the ngif directive to show the loading spinner, when the file is uploading.
So you could have a variable called "uploading", which is either true or false depending on if you are uploading a file.
See the snippet below as a reference:

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="uploading"></mat-spinner>
```

I hope that, what you where looking for.

Comment: Yes when uploading that is fine. I am talking about the time between when the user clicks the upload button and the windows file picker dialog shows.

Comment: Okay. Are you looking for a way to make the popup appears faster or to show some loading screen as you wait?

Comment: I edited my original post to show what I am talking about. That screen is taking 5-7 seconds to appear. I need to show the user some sort of indication that it is loading. so I need a way to intercept that call so that I can add a loading screen

Comment: Okay. What I would do would be to create another function, which is responsible for opening the file input, and at the same time also used to display a loading icon.
Like this `openFileUpload() {
        document.getElementById('fileUpload').click();
        this.displayLoading = true
    }`
And Then I would remove the loading screen based on if af file has been selected or not

Answer (score 0):

The way you can do it is to add a boolean flag and besides the `change` event you need to add a `click` event too.

In the ts file:

```
// add a property to your class
public isOpening = false; // you can set it to true in the click event

// make sure to set it false in this method
handleFileInput(event: Event) {
 this.isOpening = false;
 ...
}
```

In the html template:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="!isOpening"> // you can hide the form after the user triggers the event
    <label for="file">Choose File</label>
    <input type="file"
           id="file"
           (click) = "this.isOpening = true" // or create a method in the ts file
           (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
</div>

// here add a div or a spinner or whatever you like
<div *ngIf="isOpening"> Please wait! Dialog is opening...</div>
```

Comment: This Almost works. The problem is the handleFileInput only gets hit if they upload a file. If they decide not to upload and hit cancel then the  "Please wait! Dialog is opening.." message doesnt go away.

Comment: hmm, that's true. and unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no way to determine if the user hits cancel.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows a spinner while uploading an image, and places this image as a full width css background banner. It also removes the spinner in case the cancel button was hit. The css included also hides the non stylable file input element.

```
// component.html
<div class="banner" [style.background-image]="'url(' + base64 + ')'">
  <div><i class="fa-solid fa-photo-film"></i>...upload image</div>
  <input type="file" class="file-input" (change)="handleUpload($event)">
  <div class="loader" *ngIf="isLoading"></div>
</div>

// component.ts
base64 = '';
isLoading = false;

handleUpload(event: any) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  if (!file) {
    this.isLoading = false;
    return;
  }
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = () => {
    this.base64 = reader.result as string;
    this.isLoading = false;
  };
}
```

The css to hide the non-stylable file input element and to create a spinner.

```
// component.css
.banner {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 360px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: background 1s linear;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.banner input {
  display: none;
}
.loader {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 4px solid #2b2b2b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: rotation 1s linear infinite;
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
.loader::after {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}
@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```